# Click function in jquery happens twice

Tags: php, jquery, html

#### HTML Section

```
<div class="right-part ap-search-8">
    <h5 class="insta-search-head"><?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('Instant Search Filters'); ?>:</h5>
    <label class="tag alltags" title="<?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('All Tags'); ?>"> 
      <input type="checkbox"> 
      <span class="tag-text"><?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('All Tags'); ?></span>
    </label>
    <?php
     $default_filters = (empty($GLOBALS['zhemr']['default_patient_search_filters'])) ? array('fname|lname|mname','pd_pid'): (array)$GLOBALS['zhemr']['default_patient_search_filters']; ?>
    <label class="tag <?php if(in_array('fname|lname|mname',$default_filters)){ ?>ap-search-9<?php }?>" data-filter="fname|lname|mname" title="<?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('Name'); ?>"> 
      <input type="checkbox"> 
      <span class="tag-text"><?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('Name'); ?></span>
    </label>       
    <label class="tag <?php if(in_array('pd_pid',$default_filters)){ ?>ap-search-9<?php }?>" data-filter="pd_pid" title="<?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('PID'); ?>"> 
      <input type="checkbox"> 
      <span class="tag-text"><?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt('PID'); ?></span>
    </label>
       <?php foreach($this->filters as $field_id => $filter) :
          ?>
          <label class="tag <?php if(in_array($field_id,$default_filters)){ ?>ap-search-9<?php }?>"   data-filter="<?php echo $field_id; ?>" title="<?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt($filter); ?>"> 
            <input type="checkbox"> 
            <span class="tag-text"><?php echo \Application\Plugin\Common::z_xlt($filter); ?></span>
          </label>
          <?php 
        endforeach;
      ?>     

  </div>
```

#### JS Section

```
$(".ap-search-8 .tag").click(function(ev) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("alltags")) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("ap-search-9")) {
      if ($(".ap-search-9").length < 2) return;
      $(this).removeClass("ap-search-9");
      $(this).removeClass("ap-search-adv");
      $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("ap-search-9");
      $(this).addClass("ap-search-adv");
      $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', "checked");
    }
  } else {
    if ($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")) {
      //$(".ap-search-8 .tag").not(".alltags").addClass('ap-search-9');
      $(".ap-search-8 .tag").not(".alltags").addClass('ap-search-9').find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', "checked");
    } else {
      //(".ap-search-8 .tag").not(".alltags").removeClass('ap-search-9');
      $(".ap-search-8 .tag").not(".alltags,[data-filter='fname|lname|mname'],[data-filter='pd_pid']").removeClass('ap-search-9').find("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
    }
  }
  var filter_fields = "";
  var i = 0;
  top.$(".ap-search-9").each(function() {
    i++;
    if (filter_fields != '') filter_fields += "****";
    filter_fields += $(this).attr("data-filter");
  });
  if ($('.ap-search-8').find('.ap-search-9').length == $('.ap-search-8').find('label.tag').not('.alltags').length) {
    $('.ap-search-8').find('.alltags').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', 'true');
  } else {
    $('.ap-search-8').find('.alltags').find("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
  }
  angular.element($('#angular_jquery_map')).scope().filterFields = filter_fields;
  requestRunning = true;
  memorizeSearchFilters();
  return false;
});
```

Here the click function happens twice for 'Alltags' label and also for other labels it works properly. If we put the  preventDefault() function outside the if condition then the clicks become ok but the else part ie, click wrote for 'Alltags' doesnt work. The checkbox check and uncheck not happens. If anyone Knows the solution please help.

Comment: PLease create a statice example what you want, because you have php tags in your example code.

Comment: You please ignore that php tags.Using other class the click function is done

Comment: can you please check this fiddle and let me know what exact output you want http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/866/

Comment: Yes the output you make is correct.The problem is that during the click in Alltags click triggers twice and in other case of label their is no problem.